# Batch script with spaces in folder path

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, spaces

I have written the following code to remove both files and sub-folders from a number of folders (Folder 1, Folder 2 etc. The script works successfully when there are no spaces in the folder names however, it fails to delete the temp file (files2del.txt) and the sub-folders when there spaces. The path ends on a dot.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set folder[0]=Folder 1
set folder[1]=Folder 2

for /l %%s in (0,1,1) do (
  set "var=C:\directory\!folder[%%s]!"
  dir "!var!"/s/b/a | sort /r >> !var!\files2del.txt
  for /f "delims=;" %%D in (!var!\files2del.txt) do (del /q "%%D" & rd "%%D")
  pause
)
exit
```

The below line seems to be the issue.

```
for /f "delims=;" %%D in (!var!\files2del.txt) do (del /q "%%D" & rd "%%D")
```

I have tried various things like %, quotes etc. but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=;" %%D in ("!var!\files2del.txt") do (del /q "%%D" & rd "%%D")
```

You can use double quotes in when reading a file when `usebackq` option is used.Tough it is not mentioned in `FOR /?` message.

Comment: From the `usebackq` portion of the `FOR` command help file: **allows the use of double quotes to quote file names in file-set**